# MongoDB and Hadoop basics

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

Is hadoop used just as a data processing?  Main benefit of Hadoop is ability to read the same file on different machines and process it there and then reduce.

With MongoDB and Hadoop adapter we can proceed data on each node but data supply still goes from the one MongoDb machine (disk).  So search in 10Gb with help of 10 Hadoop nodes can be the same as without Hadoop at all (just on mongodb machine)

For me it looks like a bottleneck.  Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

No, Hadoop is actually 2 things, HDFS(the storage layer) and Mapreduce(the processing layer).

Only parts of a file and not the whole file. When you store a file in HDFS, it first gets chopped into blocks of 64M (default, but configurable) and then each block gets stored on a different machine in a replicated manner. Each block is read on the machine where it is located and gets proceed there itself in parallel with other blocks on other machines.

Why do you want to move your MongoDB data first into your Hadoop cluster and then process it?You can very well use sharding and MapReduce to process the MongoDB data in a distributed manner. You might find this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) useful.

Comment: even multiple shards in MongoDB might not be nearly as powerful as a large Hadoop cluster - but sharding the source will allow you to stream it into Hadoop faster as the mongo-hadoop connector can pull data from shards more efficiently.